# How to use custom locale files in ZF1?

Tags: zend-framework, locale

Is it possible to use custom locales (or modify existing ones) in a ZF1 application?  (That is, my own versions of the files in `Zend/Locale/Data`.)

e.g. something like:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale("/path/to/mylocale.xml");
```

(This looks to be impossible, because `Zend_Locale_Data::_findRoute()` is hard-coded to look in a specific directory for locale files.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @akond I'm trying to amend and enhance an existing translation file (in this case `Zend/Locale/Data/ha.xml`) but I'm not able to modify the ZF1 source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible, but you can file a bug into their bug system
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel

Registration is required.